# What was the first work of literature to feature the Vulcan nerve pinch?

Tags: story-identification, star-trek

I know that the Vulcan nerve pinch was first shown on Star Trek, now my question is: when was it first shown in the printed page? It’s mostly academic, but other people might find it interesting.

Comment: Just as an aside - There was an instance of this type of pinch a couple of years earlier in Doctor Who (Aztecs arc), but it wasn't novelized until the 1980's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of the original series episodes received a novelisation by James Blish. These were released almost contemporaneously with the TV show. [Star Trek 1](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_1) was the first ever Star Trek tie-in novel and was published in 1967, just six months after the episode [TOS: The Naked Time](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Naked_Time_(episode)) was broadcast. It contains the following passage.

> *“Sorry, neither,” Uhura said. She threw a glance deliberately over
> Sulu’s left shoulder; as he jerked in that direction, **Spock’s hand
> caught him on the right shoulder with the Vulcanian nerve pinch. Sulu
> went down on the deck like a sack of flour.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek 1: Naked Time](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_1)</sup></sub>

The first reference to the nerve-pinch in a *non-novelisation* fiction book is in [Spock Messiah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spock,_Messiah!) from 1976, the second Trek tie-in novel not based on a specific episode.

> “Problems,” she said unhappily. “Less than an hour ago, a tall hillman
> wearing a black and red clan mask went into Chag Gara’s house. When he
> came out, he was carrying a figure wrapped in a blanket over one
> shoulder. Ker said a couple of the neighbors tried to interfere, but
> the hooded man paralyzed them with just a touch. So they let him carry
> Chag Gara away.”
>
> “The nerve pinch!” McCoy burst out.
>
> “Yes,” Kirk said nodding somberly. “It has to be Spock. Only a Vulcan
> can do that, and now he’s got Gara.”

Interestingly, the first tie-in novel not based on an episode ([Spock Must Die!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spock_Must_Die!)) also heavily featured Spock, but had no nerve-pinching.

Answer (score 2):

Reposting Valorum's comment as an answer:

Novelised versions of Star Trek episodes were published around the same time they were screened: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_(Bantam_Books). So this is likely the first literary appearance.

Comment: As much as I hate to downvote my own words, there was a reason I posted it as a comment rather than as a stub answer.